# "hit the big time” vs “make the big time”

Tags: idioms

Are there any differences in the meaning of or when we use the idioms 'hit the big time' and 'make the big time'? The definitions in the Cambridge Dictionary are:

- She finally hit the big time (= became famous or successful) with her latest novel.
- You've really made the big time now (= become famous or successful).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Hit the big time" is an [idiom](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/hit+the+big+time). "Made the big time" sounds like a corruption of that, perhaps when people confuse it with another idiom, "[made it big](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/made+it+big)".

This [Google ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hit%20the%20big%20time%2C%20made%20the%20big%20time&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chit%20the%20big%20time%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmade%20the%20big%20time%3B%2Cc0) shows the former is used far more often, and while you can't always reach definite conclusions based on ngrams, the trend is pretty clear.